# Change div id if spaces exist in id

Tags: javascript

I am using

```
 <div id="123456ABC" class="classname" onclick="javascript:AddValue(aa.value,'33',bb.value,'1000')"></div>
<div id="78904 bbc" class="classname1" onclick="javascript:AddValue(aa.value,'55',bb.value,'2000')"></div>
```

I need to remove the spaces and text after space in the id if space exist in the id

in the above case i need the id as id=123456ABC and id=78904

Comment: _I need to remove the spaces and text after space in the id if space exist in the id_. Can please clarify this line

Comment: Are you creating the Id dynamic ? ?

Comment: So show us what have you tried? I suggest looping elements, check it's ID and find space in there, if found - do replace logic

Comment: How can you have two ids

Comment: better to use the trin while giving generating the dynamic id.

Comment: @PunitGajjar trim will not work if space is inside string

Comment: you can use str.replace function then.

Comment: Best solution if i tell you then , try to use str_replace(' ', '', $string); of the php function while generating your id , this way you will not have to add the javascript code as given in the ans,  though that ans is very use full be logically it should be better to remove the space while we are generating the id dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```js
$( "div" ).each( function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   var spaceIndex = id.indexOf(" ");
   id = spaceIndex == -1 ? id : id.substring(0, spaceIndex);
  $(this).attr("id", id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="123456ABC" class="classname" onclick="javascript:AddValue(aa.value,'33',bb.value,'1000')"></div>
<div id="78904 bbc" class="classname1" onclick="javascript:AddValue(aa.value,'55',bb.value,'2000')"></div>
```

Comment: good one ,  but how about if he use the str_replace from the php while  generating the id dynamically.

Comment: @PunitGajjar not aware of OP's context, but yes if he doesn't want it why generate it at first place? But it is upto OP  to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script to remove inner space.

```
str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

more information provided here:-

[How to remove spaces from a string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963182/how-to-remove-spaces-from-a-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove spaces from all *div* then you can try code below:

```
$.each($(div), function(k, v) {
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var temp = id.split(" ");
     $(this).attr('id', temp[0]);
});
```

Hope, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to strip out the spaces (assuming you have the ID in a variable called `originalId`):

```
var noSpaceId = originalId.replace(/ +/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code to remove string after space for all the divs.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id',(this.id).split(' ')[0]);
  });
})
```

Please look in to https://jsfiddle.net/2kaak2ur/