# Remove space between words in string javascript js React

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, removing-whitespace

I'm using React (hooks) and in a component I have postcodes with a space in them in strings:
 eg "B72 1JL".

I need to remove the space in the middle of the postcodes so it is "B721JL" and also possibly any spaces before or after the postcode.

I've googled for ages and cannot find anything that will work. I know i probably need regex...but pretty confused!
Help appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove spaces from a string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963182/how-to-remove-spaces-from-a-string-using-javascript)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp You can remove spaces with the .trim() method in javascript.

Answer (score 19):

Use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to change the space for an empty space.

```
const str = "B72 1JL";

// Replacing " " (space) to "" empty space
const res = str.replace(/ /g, '')
console.log(res); // BJ721JL
```

Comment: That only replaces a single space. To replace all spaces, you would use `str.replace(/ /g, '')`

Comment: You are right, thanks! I will edit my answer!